# DB2 .NET data provider error on updating iSeries table

Tags: entity-framework-4, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a strange problem. While updating an AS400 table, I am getting the following error

> ERROR [55019] [IBM][AS] SQL7008N  REXX variable '< table name>' contains inconsistent data.

The same code is working perfectly on MSSQL 2008

After searching on internet I found that this problem arises when I update a `Non-journaled` table on AS400

For which I have to enable the `journaling` for that table. This cannot be a solution as I don't have access to the AS400 server.

The workaround mentioned on internet is to add a `NOT NULL` clause to queries like `INSERT,UPDATE, DELETE` again this is not possible in my case as i am not executing query directly instead using `DBContext` for the same.

Another workaround is to set `isolationlevel/commitmode` to `NOCOMMIT or 32`. I have tried to set both in the web config but failed getting error `System.ArgumentException: Invalid argument` and exception `Entity Exception: The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.`

So the question is simple how to do it ??

Comment: Is your framework trying to COMMIT the update?

Comment: Your best bet is to investigate if there is a way for you to turn off the use of transactions.

Comment: Interesting to see `REXX` in the error message note. What platform runs the query? What REXX is running? What driver is used? A couple different approaches might fit different setups.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the DefaultIsolationLevel:

```
iDB2Connection cn = new iDB2Connection();
cn.ConnectionString = "DataSource=myiSeries; DefaultIsolationLevel=Chaos;";
```

While old, this [Redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246440.html) has some good information.